# Magento_Customer/js/customer-data not returning product items data

Tags: magento2.4.4, customer-data

I am in the process of upgrading magento 2.3.5 ( commerce version ) to 2.4.4 ( commerce version ) commerce version also known as enterprise edition

On testing the 2.4.4 version I noticed that the code `customerData.get('cart')().items;` does not return the customer's cart

Refer below code on the complete code file on `checkout-loader.js`

```
define([
    'rjsResolver',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery'
], function (resolver, customerData, $) {
    'use strict';

    return function (checkoutLoader) {

        var mixin = {

            gtmEventTrigger: function() {

                console.log("Init Checkout Loader");
                var product_name = 'n/a';
                var product_sku = 'n/a';
                var product_price = 'n/a';
                var product_brand = 'n/a';
                var product_category = 'n/a';
                var product_variant = 'n/a';
                var product_market_price = 'n/a';
                var product_wow_cashback = 'n/a';
                var product_shipping_wm = 'n/a';
                var product_shipping_em = 'n/a';
                // empty
                var cart_items = customerData.get('cart')().items;
                var product_detail = {};
                var products = [];

                console.log("customer Data");
                console.log(customerData);

                // the cart_items here is empty
                $(cart_items).each(function(index,productData){

                    product_detail = {};

                    product_name = productData['product_name'];
                    product_sku = productData['product_sku'];
                    product_price = productData['product_price_value'];
                    product_brand = productData['product_brand'];
                    product_category = productData['product_category'];
                    product_variant = productData['product_variant'];
                    product_market_price = productData['product_market_price'];
                    product_wow_cashback = productData['product_wow_cashback'];
                    product_shipping_wm = productData['product_shipping_wm'];
                    product_shipping_em = productData['product_shipping_em'];

                    product_detail = {
                        'name':product_name,
                        'id':product_sku,
                        'price':product_price,
                        'brand':product_brand,
                        'category':product_category,
                        'variant':product_variant,
                        'quantity':productData['qty'],
                        'dimension17':product_price,
                        'dimension18':product_market_price,
                        'dimension19':product_wow_cashback,
                        'dimension20':product_shipping_wm,
                        'dimension21':product_shipping_em,
                    }

                    products.push(product_detail);
                })

                dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'ecommerceCheckout',
                'eventDetails.category': 'Ecommerce',
                'eventDetails.action': 'Checkout Step 1',
                'eventDetails.nonInteraction': 'false',
                'ecommerce': {
                    'currencyCode': 'MYR',
                    'checkout': {
                        'actionField': {
                            'step': 1
                        },
                        'products': products
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

        };

        mixin.gtmEventTrigger();

        return $.extend(checkoutLoader, mixin);
    };
});
```

This is what I get on the console tab of browser developer tools

[image]

notice that the product array item list is empty

the item is in  the product cart as per below image

[image]

also I check on the browser Developer tools in Application tab and found that the data is in the localstorage, so the data is indeed there

[image]

I am not sure what changes happen in magento 2.4.4 that causes this data not able to be captured using the code `customerData.get('cart')().items` as it works fine in the magento 2.3.5

Requesting help from someone who understand and manage to found the fixture on this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have any changes related to **customerData** in the theme then it will cause issue in latest version because there are some changes in customer-data.js. So you can check below path and copy customer-data.js from the vendor/Magento/module-customer to :

```
/app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/themename/Magento_Customer/web/js/customer-data.js
```

Also make your changes in new copied customer-data.js file in the theme.
One more thing I see in your console there are 8 errors and 1 warning is showing so i suggest you to please fix these console errors as well.